# How to save data in object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this object and I want to save data in the `Obj.document.metadata.name`
example: `newData = Obj.document.metadata.name`
but it didn't work.
I will appreciate all answers.

```
var Obj =
        {
            "document": {
                "metadata": {
                    "name": "",
                    "date": "",
                    "autor": ""
                 } 
             }
         }
```

Comment: did you get an error message?

Comment: Have you tried `Obj.document.metadata.name = newData;`?

Comment: FYI, this is not a JSON object, this is a JavaScript object. And it's really not clear what exactly are you trying to do. Do you want to assign a value to one of the properties or do you want to assign one of the properties to a variable? Either way, you should read [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Comment: @Madhu: I removed the `json` tag on purpose, why did you add it again? The question has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @Xerardoo it has `json` object structure right? Thats why i added..

Comment: @Madhu: Only because it has similar syntax doesn't mean it's the same thing. What do you think `a = {"foo": 42}` is? JavaScript? JSON? Wrong! It's a Python dictionary, but you don't see me add the python tag here (because it's completely irrelevant).

Comment: @Madhu How do you know what json object's structure looks like? Json object is a native JS object having methods like `parse()` and `stringify()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Obj.document.metadata.name="Xerardoo"
```

temporarily you can save this way. But it will be lost if page refresh

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this also

```
Obj["document"]["metadata"]["name"] = "Value"
```